# How to solve this differential equation using mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I have a following differential equation where w is a function of x alone , a , b c, d,e, k, m,  qi's  are the constants. How to solve this in mathematica. I used DSolve but I did get any thing in return.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}-2\frac{(2\pi)^2}{b}\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+\left(\left(\frac{2\pi}{b}\right)^4-a^4\right)w=2\frac{c^4}{d}f(x)\\
f(x)=\frac{1}{km}\sum_1^L P_{i}\sin(n\pi e)\delta(x-q_{i})
\end{align*}

Comment: can you write at least some mma codes?

Comment: It is unclear whether your summation variable is n or i.  Your expression for `f[x]` does not make a lot of sense the way its written.

Comment: The summation is on i

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation involves `DiracDelta`. You can, of course, use the Laplace (or Fourier) transform to replace your DE by an *algebraic* equation. You don't mention the value of $n$ in $sin(n\pi e)$ and, as written, a number of the constants can be ignored or re-scaled.